# How to track and send user activity to database

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I did some research but can't decide what is the best way to track and save user activities for example user login, logout, database changes and what was changed (added, edited, deleted) to a database.
I'm using angular as frontend and spring boot with hibernate as backend. I want to do it on the server side but I'm quite new to this, where can I find a good example to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To track user login you can use Spring's `ApplicationListener` to listen to the various `ApplicationEvent` that can occur during the login process. You can listen for various authentication failure events and success event. To audit the database you can use [Hibnerate Envers](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#envers) and its `@Audited` annotation to audit changes to your database.